# How to add one more column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to add one more column in my existing dataframe
example

```
  In[16] df1
  Out[16]:
         0           
  0  MDS31505B
```

But i want to add one more column which should be added at beginning at ) index column

```
  In[16] df1
  Out[16]:
          0            1         
  0    SKUID     MDS31505B
```

i am trying this but it does not affect

```
   df1.insert(loc=0, column='0', value=SKUID)
```

name 'SKUID' is not defined

Comment: df1["new_column"] = "MDS31505B"

Comment: `SKUID` should be a string: `df1.insert(loc=0, column='0', value="SKUID")`

Answer (score 0):

you can also try df1.insert(0,0,"skid")